# Как выделить пункт меню, если пользователь находится на странице, на которую пункт меню ведёт?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нужно как-то поработать с адресом текущей страницы. Может подскажете схемы реализации подобного механизма?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname; //  Только путь
var url = window.location.href;     // Полный URL
```

Что с этим делать? Используем [регулярные выражения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) или [методы String](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) например

```
if (/^\/about/.test(pathname)) {
  // путь начинается с /about
  // допустим, что у пункта меню есть класс .about-link
  $('a.about-link').addClass('is-active');
}

// другой вариант,  использовать CSS селекторы 
$('a[href^=' + pathname + ']').addClass('is-active')

// варианты разных методов:  
// pathname.includes('about') // false, true    
// pathname.match('about') // возвратит null или массив
// pathname.indexOf('about') // индекс вхожднения или -1
```

Вы может "подстроить" свою верстку по логику, которую будете использовать при определении пути в javasctipt, использовать соглашения по именованию css-классов, `rel=...`, data-атрибуты или href-атрибуты. Например ищем все ссылки на странице, которые содержат начальную часть пути из `window.location` и добавляем к ним класс `.is-active`.

Answer (score 0):

Каждый пункт меню ведет на отдельный html файл.

К примеру файл называется about.html, после нажатия на пункт меню "Про нас", вы на него переходите и в этом файле будет пункт меню - "Про нас" выделен цветом